# Filtering the Array Object by Matching SubObject values

Tags: javascript, jquery, array-filter, arrayobject

I have an array of objects:

```
sampledata = [{
    "id": 1,
    "parameter": {
        "Num_Of_Floors":"2",
        "East":"10",
        "Window_Type":"Window Type 1"
    },
    "energy": -145.9,
    "pv": 83.72
}, {
    "id2": 2,
    "parameter": {
        "Num_Of_Floors":"2",
        "East":"10",
        "Window_Type":"Window Type 2"
    },  
    "energy": -145.9,
    "pv": 83.72
}];
```

I want to get some of the object's attributes if that object's `parameter` value matches a given input.

I have tried:

```
let x={Num_Of_Floors: "2", East: "10", Window_Type: "Window Type 1"}
return this.sampledata.filter(data=> data['parameter']===x)
```

Based on the matching `parameter` object I want to return `energy` and `pv` attribute from the array object.
Result:

```
{
 "energy": -145.9,
  "pv": 83.72
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can filter my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the filter method,use `array#every` to compare each value of `sampedata` and `x` and then use `array#map` to get `pv` and `energy`

```js
const sampledata = [{ "id": 1, "parameter": { "Num_Of_Floors":"2", "East":"10", "Window_Type":"Window Type 1" }, "energy": -145.9, "pv": 83.72 }, { "id2": 2, "parameter": { "Num_Of_Floors":"2", "East":"10", "Window_Type":"Window Type 2" }, "energy": -145.9, "pv": 83.72
}];

let x= { Num_Of_Floors: "2", East: "10", Window_Type: "Window Type 1"}

var result = sampledata
              .filter(obj => Object
                .keys(obj.parameter)
                .every(k => obj.parameter[k] === x[k]))
              .map(({energy,pv}) => ({energy,pv}));
              
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your quick response..its working fine.But let suppose if we are so many attribute energy,pv ,...so on then we need to map each attribute as u have u map..or is there any other approach plz suggest

Comment: In case you want to map all property, you can return back object otherwise you have to map property individually

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to iterate the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of `x`, and check if all `x` values equal the same values of `parameter`. After filtering the object, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array's objects to the required format:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"parameter":{"Num_Of_Floors":"2","East":"10","Window_Type":"Window Type 1"},"energy":-145.9,"pv":83.72},{"id2":2,"parameter":{"Num_Of_Floors":"2","East":"10","Window_Type":"Window Type 2"},"energy":-145.9,"pv":83.72}];

const x = {Num_Of_Floors: "2", East: "10", Window_Type: "Window Type 1"};

const result = data.filter(({ parameter }) =>       
  Object.keys(x).every((key) => x[key] === parameter[key]))
  .map(({ energy, pv }) => ({ energy, pv }));
  
console.log(result);
```